# Selecting rows in cvs file and write them in another csv file

Tags: python, csv

I have a csv file with 2 columns (titles are value, image). The value list contains values in ascending order (0,25,30...), and the image list contains pathway to images (e.g. X.jpg). Total lines are 81 including the titles (that is, there are 80 values and 80 images)

[image: screenshot of a couple of columns in a spreadsheet]

What I want to divide this list 4-ways. Basically the idea is to have a spread of pairs of images.

In the first group I took the image part of every two near rows (2+3, 4+5....), and wrote them in a new csv file. I write each image in a different column. Here's the code:

```
import csv

f = open('random_sorted.csv')
csv_f = csv.reader(f)

i = 0
prev = ""

#open csv file for writing
with open('first_group.csv', 'wb') as test_file:
    csv_writer = csv.writer(test_file)
    csv_writer.writerow(["image1"] + ["image2"])
    for row in csv_f:
        if i%2 == 0 and i!=0:
            #print prev + "," + row[1]
            csv_writer.writerow([prev] + [row[1]])
        else:
            prev = row[1]
        i = i+1
```

Here's the output of this:

[image]

I want to keep the concept similar with the rest 3 groups(write into a new csv file the paired images and having two columns), but just increase the spread. That is, pair together every 5 rows (i.e. 2+7 etc.), every 7 (i.e. 2+9 etc.), and every 9 rows together. Would love to get some directions as to how to execute it. I was lucky with the first group (just learned about the remainder/divider option in the CodeAcademy course, but can't think of ideas for the other groups.

Comment: Exactly what difference to you want for each of the four groups. If the first difference is 1, it doesn't seem like there would ever be any with a difference as much as 5, 7, or 9 with only doing 4 groups. Showing the desired output would be very helpful.

Comment: edited and added the output. the values are ranging from 0-300 with jumps of 25, but vary in the number of times they appear. Basically, the middle numbers (125,150,175) appear much more than the rest. This is why the spread would make a difference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First collect all the rows in the csv file in a list:

```
with open('random_sorted.csv') as csvfile:
        csv_reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=';')
        headers = next(csv_reader)
        rows = [row for row in csv_reader]
```

Then set your required step size (5, 7 or 9) and identify the rows on the basis of their index in the list of rows:

```
with open('first_group.csv', 'wb') as test_file:
    csv_writer = csv.writer(test_file)
    csv_writer.writerow(["image1"] + ["image2"])

    step_size = 7 # set step size here
    seen = set() # here we remember images we've already seen
    for x in range(0, len(rows)-step_size):
        img1 = rows[x][1]
        img2 = rows[x+step_size][1]
        if not (img1 in seen or img2 in seen):
            csv_writer.writerow([img1, img2])
            seen.add(img1)
            seen.add(img2)
```

Comment: That looks great! For the first row, did you mean my_reader=csv_reader?

Comment: Hi @yvesperisman - so in the file "random_sorted" there  are 80 values (excluding the titles). The first code that I used generated a list of 40 pairs, whereas your code adds the "step_size" for every item in my list, thus generating 80 pairs. The aim is to have each item appears only one time in the new list. How can I fix this?

Comment: Aha. The simplest solution would be to keep a set of the items that you've already seen, `seen=set()`, add the image ids to them as you write them, `seen.add(img1)`, and before you write a new image, check if you have already seen it, `if not img1 in seen:`.

Comment: That sounds good. Where exactly should I insert the functions you've mentioned within the existing code?

Comment: I've edited the answer. One thing that isn't clear still is what you want to do with pairs where you have seen one item, but not the other. For example, in your first example, suppose you start from a file with 81 lines. What would you want to do with the 81rst item? In the edited solution it will be ignored, but I'm not sure that's what you want.

Comment: Thanks for the help so far! for the purpose of simplification, let's assume we have a list of 10 items. I guess I'm thinking that this pairs would be best: 1-3, 5-7, 9-2, 4-6, 8-10. The idea (if im trying to conceptualize it) is to create a loop that will attempt to create a pair within the given spread, and if not possible, will go back to the beginning of the list and find another item to pair with. This way we can get every item being paired only once, and minimized the number of pairs that won't be in the spread. Does that make sense?